# Can´t add field without foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two database one local and other in production.

In one of them I have column `IdNivelDominio` without `FK` but if I open *Constraints* folder and I have something like:

`DF_EvaluacionDetalleCompetenciasFuncionales_IdNivelDominio`

So I want to reply this field into my another database as:

```
ALTER TABLE Reclutamiento.EvaluacionDetalleCompetenciasFuncionales
ADD IdNivelDominio INT NOT NULL;
```

But I get error:

> ALTER TABLE only allows columns to be added that can contain nulls, or
>   have a DEFAULT definition specified, or the column being added is an
>   identity or timestamp column, or alternatively if none of the previous
>   conditions are satisfied the table must be empty to allow addition of
>   this column. Column 'IdNivelDominio' cannot be added to non-empty
>   table 'EvaluacionDetalleCompetenciasFuncionales' because it does not
>   satisfy these conditions.

Problem is that field is not linked with a foreign key (into original table) so I can´t add constraint.

Can anyone explain me how it occurs? or there any way to do constraint without foreign key? Regards

Comment: If you have data in your table, add a `default` keyword to your `alter` statement.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Reclutamiento.EvaluacionDetalleCompetenciasFuncionales
ADD IdNivelDominio INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

You're trying to add a new column that should be `NOT NULL` to table with data. You need to specify what value will be in that new column because it's `NOT NULL`

Comment: Nice!, but why it add a reference in constraints folder?

Comment: Because there exists Constraints with some conditions for that column. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx